# DDL SelectedIndexChanged() does not fire on first ListItem (ASP.Net C#)

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, drop-down-menu

I created a custom Templated User Control, for the purpose of having a standard "container" to use around our web app, but allow whatever controls you want inside of it -- pretty much like a Template Column of a GridView/DataGrid. Problem I'm having is that when I place a DropDownList control inside my custom control, the SelectedIndexChanged method of that DDL doesn't always fire, and I am stumped as to why.

I created a small test page with my custom control and a single DDL, which has some hard coded values, to replicate the problem:

```
<uc1:ExpandCollapseRegion ID="xpcColor" runat="server" Title="Pick a Color" AlwaysOpen="true">
<LayoutTemplate>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Color:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yellow" Value="3" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="4" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="5" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Indigo" Value="6" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Violet" Value="7" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblColorChoice" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</LayoutTemplate>
```

The code-behind looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ((Label)xpcColor.FindControl("lblColorChoice")).Text = "";
        }
    }

    protected void ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DropDownList ddlColor = ((DropDownList)xpcColor.FindControl("ddlColor")))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlColor.SelectedValue))
            {
                ((Label)xpcColor.FindControl("lblColorChoice")).Text = "You chose the color " + ddlColor.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                ((Label)xpcColor.FindControl("lblColorChoice")).Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

All that is supposed to happen here is to show in the Label what color was picked, but if no color was picked to then just clear the label. Very simple, no biggie, however....

100% of the time, when I pick a color the SelectedIndexChanged method fires, and the Label control is updated with the text. I can pick one color, the another, then another, and so forth over and over and the thing works great. However, if after choosing a color, I select the blank item of the DDL, the SelectedIndexChanged method *does not* fire, ever.

I wanted to see if this had something to do with the value being selected, so I added a new ListItem before the blank one (making the blank ListItem the second option):

```
<asp:ListItem Text="White" Value="0" />
```

Now when I run the page, I can choose a color, the label is updated, choose the blank one and the label is cleared, but if I select "White", the page does a PostBack yet the SelectedIndexChanged method once again *does not* fire.

I have never run into this before and admit I am a bit stumped as to the cause.

The problem may well be in my custom control, but I am hesitant to think so as the DDL functions correctly for all selections, except for the first one. Also the DDL choice as well as the Label text survives a PostBack, so I am not sure this is a ViewState issue either.

I'm still Googl'ing this, but I am pretty much stumped here what's going on. If anyone else has seen this, run across this, or may have some input of possible fixes, I am all ears.  Much appreciated.

-- Andrew

Comment: If the ddl starts with the first option selected, and you select it (the first option) again, it didn't change. So the event doesn't trigger. Try to initialize the ddl with another value. I'm tryingo to say that if the old selectedIndex is 0 and the new selectedIndex is 0, the 'change' didn't occurs.

Comment: Is the postback code from your usercontrol, or from the page hosting the user control?  I assume it's the host page, since this control itself wouldn't have "xpcColor" as a local member.

Comment: If in your ASPX file, you explicitly mark a different ListItem as 'selected', does that one become the one that refuses to fire the event?  What I'm driving at is, I'm wondering if there's some correlation between the ListItem that is considered "selected" at the time LayoutTemplate is evaluated, and the ListItem that refuses to fire the event.

Comment: @Tocco -- please reread what I posted, I stated that the SelectedIndexChanged() handler method does not fire when selecting the first ListItem *after* having made a previous choice.

Comment: @mikemanne -- correct, the `SelectedIndexChanged()` handler is in the hosting page, as the `xpcColor` user control has no real knowledge of the controls placed inside its `LayoutTemplate`. The `SelectedIndexChanged()` handler fires just fine on any `ListItem` choice **except** the first one.

Comment: @mikemanne -- There is no `ListItem` pre-set as "Selected". When I run the page the first time and view the rendered Source, no `ListItem` is "Selected". When I make a choice and view the Source, the one I picked is now so marked. When I choose the first `ListItem`, the first one is now marked "Selected" but the event handler never fired.

Comment: You may want to try it anyway, as a debugging technique (explicitly setting a different item as selected).  Even if no listItem is rendered with a "selected" tag, the page may still be tracking a "currently selected value" (or something similar) for purposes of determining whether or not a selection has changed.

Comment: @mikemanne -- Just gave it a shot, no difference in behavior. I dictated the selected item in both the HTML side and in the code-behind. I have also set BreakPoints on the `Page_Init` and `Page_Load` of the user control, as well as the same and `SelectedIndexChanged()` in the test page and watched as each gets hit when making a choice, but the `SelectedIndexChanged()` never fires when selecting that first `ListItem`. I'm thinking something's up in the `ViewState` of the user control, but I just don't know what/where.

Comment: Found the solution! The `using()` statement in the `SelectedIndexChanged()` event handler was causing the problem. When I replaced `using (DropDownList ddlColor = ((DropDownList)xpcColor.FindControl("ddlColor")))` with `DropDownList ddlColor = (DropDownList)sender;` all is once again right in my world. :)